# Using jquery cookies to change starter image in slideshow if user is new

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies, jquery-cookie

So when a new visitor arrives on the site the starting image would be "background3.jpg" instead of starting on "background1.jpg"

Underneath you can see the script I am using on the index page which controles the slideshow.

```
<script>
   $.backstretch([
  "imgs/background1.jpg",
  "imgs/background2.jpg",
  "imgs/background3.jpg",
  "imgs/background4.jpg",
  "imgs/background5.jpg" ], {
    fade: 800,    //Speed of Fade
    duration: 2500     // The length of Time the image is display
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just test whether the cookie exists:

```
if($.cookie(cookie_name)){
    $.backstretch(
        "imgs/background1.jpg",
        "imgs/background2.jpg",
        "imgs/background3.jpg",
        "imgs/background4.jpg",
        "imgs/background5.jpg", {
            fade: 800,    //Speed of Fade
            duration: 2500     // The length of Time the image is display
    });
} else {
    //your server sends the cookies here
    dont_show_slides();
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't seem to work. It might be my fault as I accidently took out the "]" character after the "imgs/background5.jpg", I just corrected the script in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

download jquery-cookie plugin here: [link](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if($.cookie("IsNew").length==0){
            $.cookie("IsNew","somevalue");
            $.backstretch(["imgs/background1.jpg",
                          "imgs/background2.jpg",
                          "imgs/background3.jpg",
                          "imgs/background4.jpg",
                          "imgs/background5.jpg"], 
                          {fade: 800, duration :2500 });
        }
        else
        {
            $.backstretch(["imgs/background3.jpg",
                          "imgs/background1.jpg",
                          "imgs/background2.jpg",
                          "imgs/background4.jpg",
                          "imgs/background5.jpg"], 
                          {fade: 800, duration :2500 });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I just tried this script and apparently there is a syntax error.

Comment: It might be my fault as I accidently took out the "]" character after the "imgs/background5.jpg", I just corrected the original question.

Comment: Thanks for you speedy response, Just a quick question as I am a bit of a newbie. To reference the jquery.cookie do I just need to add the actual <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> file or anything more. Many thanks

Comment: <script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script> add this below main jquery libraries.

Comment: Still no luck, I think it might be interfering with http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ the backstretch script.<script src="js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

Comment: post where you importing these files. and just for check, you physically created js folder and put jquery.cookie.js in it, right?

Comment: Yes I downloaded the jquery.cookie.js file and physically put it in the js folder

Comment: could you add your html into question, please?

Comment: I have a link to the site http://thegreenery.ie/site/index.html, hopefully you can view the source code